# How to read query string values in ModelViewSet logic?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, query-string

I need to get at query string values in some viewset logic (in this case, derived from **ModelViewSet**). Everything I've read, including the Django REST Framework doc, says that **request** is an attribute of the viewset. But when I actually try to refer to it in code, no matter how I do so, I am shown the runtime error **'AddressViewSet' object has no attribute 'request'** . Here's one simplified version of the class definition that triggers the error:

```
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self, suffix, basename, detail):
        attendee = ""
        if self.request.query_params.get('attendee'):
            attendee = self.request.query_params.get('attendee')

        self.serializer_class = AddressSerializer
        self.queryset = Address.objects.all()
```

How does one read **request** properties in viewset logic in DRF?

Comment: You're overriding the incorrect method, the ViewSet is instantiated even before the request is made of course request won't be present in `__init__`. On the other hand what are you trying to do with `attendee`?

Comment: Eventually I will want to filter the queryset on any of a large number of possible combinations of query string values; attendee is just one of them that I'm using here as an example. So how do I get the query string values for filtering the queryset?

Comment: Also, how can anything be instantiated before the request is received? Why would an API view be created other than in response to a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the incorrect method. The ViewSet like all class based views in Django (All DRF views inherit from `django.views.generic.View` down the line) is instantiated (The pattern usually seen as `View.as_view()` internally creates an instance of the class) before the request is even received. This instance is used in the url patterns and when a request matching the url pattern is found a [dynamically created function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/71902e0d9f93670c4f93ff9d66095b0e571be74b/django/views/generic/base.py#L95) is called for the view which then calls `dispatch`.

Coming back to the point `__init__` is not the correct method to override, if you want to filter the queryset you should instead be overriding `get_queryset`:

```py
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Address.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        attendee = ""
        if self.request.query_params.get('attendee'):
            attendee = self.request.query_params.get('attendee')
        # Filter queryset here
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did not understand is that you can override a function **get_queryset()** but if you do that you do not assign **queryset** directly - that happens automatically. Once that overridden function is called the **request** is available as a property of the viewset, so it can be referred to there.